# Empty response when running REST application on docker with Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, sbt, akka-http

I've create a simple scala application(akka-http REST service) using SBT.

This is the application main class:

```
 object UserApiWebService extends App {

   override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("user-api-system")
     implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher
     implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

     val userApiRoute = new UserApiRoute
     val userApiRoutes = new UserApiRoutes(userApiRoute)


     val config = ConfigFactory.load()
     val host = config.getString("http.host")
     val port = config.getInt("http.port")

     println(s"Starting server on $host:$port..")
     Http().bindAndHandle(userApiRoutes.routes, host, port)
     println(s"Server started on $host:$port..")   }

 }
```

and my application.conf contains `http.host` = "127.0.0.1" and `http.port` = 9000

When I run the application in local running `sbt run` all works great.

So I decided to try docker and create a container for my Akka application.
I'm using the sbt DockerPlugin and running the command sbt docker:publishDocker it creates the docker image on local machine.

So I've started the docker container using the command

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 --name user-api user-api:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

and I can see that the container is correctly running.

If I check if the API-REST application is working correctly using the command:

```
curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9000/user/34
```

I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` as a response.

If I try the same command after entered in the container using `docker exec -it a556b8846340 /bin/bash` I get the correct response.

I'm working on a mac using macOS 10.12.6 and docker version 17.09.1-ce.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running on Mac, you need `docker-machine ip` to talk to local VM [(reference)](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/).

So your curl needs to be updated to `curl -X GET http://$(docker-machine ip):9000/user/34`

Comment: after configuring docker-machine works also on localhost, thanks